# Confusion on paths and interpretation of combination

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Going through combinatorics as a refresher, I stumbled across a problem in my notes.

What is the number of ways to go from the point $(0,0)$ to $(10,5)$ if the only moves you can make are to go up by one or to go right by one?

The answer to this question is $_{15}C_5$. Of the 15 total steps you can make choose 5 of them to make as the "up" step, and the rest have to be "right" steps in order to reach $(10,5)$.

However thinking back, isn't combination used to represent unordered sequences? In this case, the sequence "up" 5 times and then "right" 10 times is obviously different from "right" 10 times and then "up" 5 times. However, they are both the same combination sequence(unordered), so they should be counted as one path(obviously not true).

I'm confused why combination shows up in the answer if the order in which I take my "up" steps and "down" steps matter. Is my interpretation of the problem/combination wrong?

Comment: Choosing the positions of the up steps completely determines the sequence of moves.

Comment: Yes, but we count UUUUULLLLLLLLLL and LLLLLLLLLLUUUUU are completely different paths(when drawn out). But the are both the same combination so they should be counted as a sequence only once. I'm confused.

Comment: Looking in detail at a smaller example, say $(2,1)$ might remedy your confusion.

Comment: But, you must have exactly 5 U and 10 (I believe should be R not L), so everything we need to do, is to choose (say) 5 positions (when we want to go UP) in a sequence of lenght 15 (the rest are the times we go RIGHT)

Comment: @DominikKutek You're right it should be R and not L. What you're saying is I'm choosing positions and not choosing up or right? I'm a bit confused...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choosing the positions of the up steps completely determines the sequence of moves.

To illustrate, observe that choosing to place the up moves in positions 4, 7, 8, 12, and 15 produces the sequence $RRRURRUURRRURRU$ and the path

[image: path_with_initial_horizontal_move]

while choosing to place the up moves in positions 1, 6, 9, 11, and 12 produces the sequence $URRRRURRURUURRR$ and the path

[image: path_with_initial_vertical_move]

Since exactly five of the fifteen moves are upwards and the rest are rightwards, there are 
$$\binom{15}{5} = \frac{15!}{5!10!}$$
possible paths from $(0, 0)$ to $(10, 5)$ in which the only permissible moves are up or to the right.  The factor of $5!$ in the denominator represents the number of ways we could permute the up moves among themselves without producing a sequence distinguishable from the given sequence; the factor of $10!$ in the denominator represents the number of ways we could permute the rightwards moves among themselves without producing a sequence distinguishable from the given sequence.

Your confusion stems from the difference between a [set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(mathematics)), in which all the elements must be different, and a [multiset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset), in which elements are permitted to have multiplicity greater than one.

For a set $S$ with $n$ elements, a $k$-combination is a subset with $k$ elements.  The number of such subsets is 
$$C(n, k) = \binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n - k)!}$$
An arrangement of a $k$-element subset of a set with $n$ elements is a $k$-permutation.  Since there are $k!$ ways to arrange the $k$ elements in the subset, the number of $k$-permutations is 
$$P(n, k) = k!C(n, k) = k! \cdot \frac{n!}{k!(n - k)!} = \frac{n!}{(n - k)!}$$

However, when we arrange a multiset, some of the elements may be the same.  A [permutation of a multiset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Permutations_of_multisets) $M$ is an arrangement of the elements of the multiset in which each element appears exactly as many times as it appears in the multiset.

In our case, the multiset is $M = \{5 \cdot U, 10 \cdot R\}$, where $U$ represents an upward move and $R$ represents a rightward move.

A particular permutation of a multiset is determined by choosing the positions of each element in the sequence.  Perhaps it would help to consider an example in which there are more than two distinct elements in the multiset.

**Example.**  How many anagrams does the word REPETITION have?

The ten letters of the word REPETITION form the multiset $\{1 \cdot R, 2 \cdot E, 1 \cdot P, 2 \cdot T, 2 \cdot I, 1 \cdot O, 1 \cdot N\}$.  A particular anagram of the word REPETITION is determined by choosing the positions occupied by each letter.  For instance, if we place the R in the fifth position, the E's in positions 2 and 9, the P in position 1, the T's in positions 3 and 10, the I's in positions 7 and 8, the O in position 4, and the N in position 6, we obtain the anagram PETORNIIET.

The number of such anagrams is 
$$\binom{10}{1}\binom{9}{2}\binom{7}{1}\binom{6}{2}\binom{4}{2}\binom{2}{1}\binom{1}{1} = \frac{10!}{1!2!1!2!2!1!1!}$$
since we must choose one of the ten positions for the R, two of the remaining nine positions for the E's, one of the remaining seven positions for the P, two of the remaining six positions for the T's, two of the remaining four positions for the I's, one the remaining two positions for the O, and fill the final open position with the N.

Comment: Oh, that makes so much sense! Just by looking at the problem, how did you know that this was a permutation of a multiset and not a combination? By experience?

Comment: @WilsonGuo Yes, by experience.

Answer (score 1):

You are essentially lining up 15 items, called `right_1`,`right_2`,...,`right_10`,`up_1`,...,`up_5`, into a sequence to determine a route.

If you use the arrangement number, it'd be like you are assuming the two arrangements

`right_1`,`right_2`,...,`right_10`,`up_1`,...,`up_5`

`right_2`,`right_1`,...,`right_10`,`up_1`,...,`up_5`

are different, in which case you have $\ _{15}A_{15}$ different arrangements. However, they indeed result in the same route in your context, so you need to rule out the repeations. The point is `right_i` and `right_j` are identical in this problem (as well as `up_i` and `up_j`). And the final result is $$\frac{\ _{15}A_{15}}{\ _{5}A_{5}\cdot\ _{10}A_{10}}=\ _{15}C_{5}$$

Loosely speaking, combination appears in an arrangement with identical elements.